# dropdownlistfor selected value list item possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm trying to do something special here.

Here's the code I currently have for my dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SourceList, new SelectList(Model.SourceList, "Id", "Name", new { id = "SourceList" }))
```

Now this works, but it's pretty dumb what I'm doing here. In my back-end I query again to get the entire model from the id I just selected.

What I need is not the Id of the selected model, but the entire model. Is there any way of doing this?

My current JQuery callback:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetLicensesAfterSourceChange", "Permission")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "Id" : selectedStartSourceId, "sourceList" : jsonSourceList }),
            success: function (result) {
                //Do stuff here
            }
        });
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetLicensesAfterSourceChange", "Permission")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: "selectedModel" = modelFromDropDownList,
            success: function (result) {
                //Do stuff here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit far-fetched, but you could create a Javascript array representation of your entire list of source objects, and use jQuery and a simple html select ( with the id & name for the options) to retrieve the item from the array.

```
<script>
var items = [ 
{ 
   name = "een",
   value = "1",
   propertyX = "hallo"
},
{ 
   name = "twee",
   value = "2",
   propertyX = "wereld"
}
];

$("#ddlselect").change(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();

  var selectedOptionVal = $(this).val();

  var found = null;
  foreach (item in items)
  {
     if (!found && item.value == selectedOptionVal)
        found = item;
  }

  // use found if set
  if (found)
  {
  }
});

</script>

<select id="ddlselect">
  <option value="">-- kies --</option>
  <option value="1">een</option>
  <option value="2">twee</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Currently I'm just giving my model as a parameter to my controller and use a .FirstOrDefault() to get the correct model. It's this that I want to change. I want to scrap the .FirstOrDefault() as I want to return the correct object and not the selected ID and list of all objects.

Comment: Is the list of models available at the server side? ( In server cache for example? )

Comment: I'm using a wcf service, so I doubt there will be server cache. The model that I want to use is the one that I have in my dropdownlistfor.

Comment: What is in m.SourceList exactly? I'd like to help you out, but with every comment I get more confused about what you are trying to achieve. In short, it isn't possible to create a list of complete model objects with the dropdownlistfor construct, because it requires a list of SelectListItem ( which only has properties for Name, Value and Selected ). It is possible to achieve your goal, but then you should work extensively with jQuery and local javascript storage of the list of objects.

Comment: The m.SourceList is a List<SourceModel> which contains Id, Name and other parameters. If it can't be done easily, I'm just going to use the .FirstOrDefault() method which worked. I just wanted to do it a bit cleaner.